# Shortcut to exit equation in MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

My MS Word is set so that the keyboard-shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> inserts an equation.

But how do I exit this equation, without having to use the mouse or the arrow keys? In other words, I want to exit the equation editor and continue writing, but without moving my hand away from the touch type position.

I have tried to press the shortcut again, to see if it would exit the equation, but it does not.

Any ideas to how I can exit the equation in the described way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make shortcut to CharRight**

Word options -> 
Customize Ribbon -> 
Commands not in the Ribbon. Then find the entry for CharRight and assign a shortcut. I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I came here so many times when I encountered this problem until I realised the simple answer: you just press

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

again!

Comment: This used to work for me also, but not anymore. What command is "alt + =" specified as? If we knew the name of the command, then persons for whom this does not work anymore, could customize their keyboard to make it work again.

Answer (score 4):

Press the right arrow key on your keyboard, you will then be out of the equation editor and continue with typing your document.

**Update (19 September 2021):** Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> inserts/opens the Equation editor. Pressing again <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>  will take you out of the Equation editor.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to avoid moving my hands to the arrow key. I hope for a solution which will make me keep my hands on the home row.

Answer (score 0):

If you're at the end of the equation, you can just press right arrow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).